# How to use back to school gift card?

Tags: mac-appstore

I've gotten a $100 back to school from Apple, along with a recent Mac purchase. Can I pay for apps across multiple purchases, or must I spend $100 in one go? How would I go about using the gift card anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be used across multiple purchases and different stores. You should be able to redeem it App Store, iTunes Store, and iBookstore credit by going into iTunes and clicking Redeem under Quick Links.

More redemption methods are documented in [HT1574](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1574). Additionally, [Apple's Promotion FAQ](http://www.apple.com/promo/faq.html) under Card or Code Redemption has some more details.